# How can I detect if my .NET assembly is running from web site or from a desktop machine?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I just want to write code inside my assembly to detect whether it is running on a "desktop machine", or inside the context of an ASP.NET application. This is crucial guys, (licensing purposes), and I don't want to get fired because I did a mistake.

So, please, be direct and if you please give me some code snippet.

EDIT: I depend on your answers

EDIT v 2.0: What about using in the assembly:

```
[assembly: "AspNetHostingPermission (SecurityAction.RequestRefuge, Unrestricted=true)]"
```

to prevent the execution on the web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be helpful:

[How determine if application is web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179716/how-determine-if-application-is-web-application)

Comment: You're probably right. I didn't search for it and I only saw what was listed after I entered the question. So, I give you the credits.
I'll check it. Thank you.

Comment: Now that I am thinking: if someone create an executable (console) and call it would the same code still be valid? I don't have experience with ASP.NET and don't know the tricks.

Answer (score 4):

Check whether the HttpContext.Current is null and then report it's not running as a web app, e.g.:

```
if (HttpContext.Current == null) {
     // Report that it is not running as web app.
}
```

You will have to make a reference to the System.Web in your references and you using statement.

Comment: You have a point. I merged your proposal with the above (afolkesson) in a statement.

Comment: By experience i should point out that if they check HttpContext from a new thread it will be null, also sometimes it is null even in the current thread...not so reliable as a variable...