# How to know in a class library if the hosting app is ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I am writing a class library and want to perform some conditional processing if the client/host application using the library is an ASP.NET application.

I am thinking that the simplest way of checking that would be simply to set a static reference to `System.Web.dll` in my library and then to check if the `HttpContext` object is null or not. If it is not null, then we know that we're running in the context of a Web app.

However, I am not sure if this is a fool-proof method. Is there a more sophisticated approach?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179716/how-determine-if-application-is-web-application

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Thank you very much. Your comment helped me find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext may be null in certain scenarios... And it's thread static, so not reliable in multithreaded scenarios.

You could consider using the HostingEnvironment class.