# How to get all sections of a specific type

Tags: c#, configuration

Let's say I have the following in my config:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="interestingThings" type="Test.InterestingThingsSection, Test" />
  <section name="moreInterestingThings" type="Test.InterestingThingsSection, Test" />
</configSections>

<interestingThings>
  <add name="Thing1" value="Seuss" />
</interestingThings>

<moreInterestingThings>
  <add name="Thing2" value="Seuss" />
</moreInterestingThings>
```

If I want to get either section, I can get them by name pretty easily:

```
InterestingThingsSection interesting = (InterestingThingsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("interestingThings");
InterestingThingsSection more = (InterestingThingsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("moreInterestingThings");
```

However, this relies on my code knowing how the section is named in the config - and it could be named anything.  What I'd prefer is the ability to pull all sections of type `InterestingThingsSection` from the config, regardless of name.  How can I go about this in a flexible way (so, supports both app configs and web configs)?

**EDIT:**  If you have the `Configuration` already, getting the actual sections isn't too difficult:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SectionsOfType<T>(this Configuration configuration)
    where T : ConfigurationSection
{
    return configuration.Sections.OfType<T>().Union(
        configuration.SectionGroups.SectionsOfType<T>());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> SectionsOfType<T>(this ConfigurationSectionGroupCollection collection)
    where T : ConfigurationSection
{
    var sections = new List<T>();
    foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup group in collection)
    {
        sections.AddRange(group.Sections.OfType<T>());
        sections.AddRange(group.SectionGroups.SectionsOfType<T>());
    }
    return sections;
}
```

However, how do I get the `Configuration` instance in a generally-applicable way?  Or, how do I know if I should use `ConfigurationManager` or `WebConfigurationManager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, this appears to be the best way:

```
var config = HostingEnvironment.IsHosted
    ? WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null) // Web app.
    : ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); // Desktop app.
```

Comment: A downside to this approach is that HostingEnvironment needs a reference to System.Web.. A more lightweight approach is to use `Path.GetFileName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)` as described here: [How determine if application is web application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3179933)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)` method. It opens the configuration file for the current application as a `Configuration` object.

MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way to do it but you can read your configuration file as a normal xml and then parse the sections you want. For example if it were a web application:

```
XmlDocument myConfig= new XmlDocument();
myConfig.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));
XmlNode xnodes = myConfig.SelectSingleNode("/configSections");
```

Now you can see the nodes that you care about discovering the names at runtime and then access the specific node of your configuration file.

Another solution is:

```
Path.GetFileName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)
```

If this returns "web.config", it is probably  a web application.

However, HostingEnvironment.IsHosted is intended to indicate whether an appdomain is configured to run under ASP.NET so it is not sure that yours is a web application.

Comment: `Server.MapPath` is web-application-specific, though, right?  So I'd still need to know if I have a web or desktop application.  If I know that I have one, I can just use `WebConfigurationManager` in that case; what I want is the ability to get the `Configuration` object without knowing if I need to use `WebConfigurationManager` or `ConfigurationManager`.
Having the `Configuration` object allows me to use the strongly-typed sections I've already defined rather than parse the XML directly.